# xcode make ad hoc build without device

Tags: ios, xcode

I do not have any device with me currently.

I need to make a ad hoc build to send it to my tester who has the device.

But to make a build/archive I need a device. connected

Is there any way I can make an archive IPA without any device connected.

Comment: Not sure why this had a -1, I up voted back to 0... seems like a good question, and was exactly what I needed, thanks for asking it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need to have the device connected to archive.  Just set the scheme destination pop up to "iOS Device" and archive as normal.